# Show data from a database in a textview

Tags: android, live, multiplayer

Hey there I need your help. It is probalby pretty easy. I just wanna make a button and a textView. Whenever I press the Button the value of the textView goes +1. I know how to do that, don't worry :D

I want to know now, how can I make sure that this textView changes for everybody?

For example 10 people have the app installed and if one of them presses the button the value should show change for everyone.

Displaying this live may be a problem, so can i somehow update this textview every 1 to 10 minutes?

I guess i habe to store the value of this textView somewhere in a database on a webserver?

Thank you for taking time and reading through this. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use GCM to achieve this.
You need to integrate this on your server and device side.
You can have a look on [this](https://github.com/google/gcm) to understand this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be is to store the value in database as you mentioned  and then use push notification to update it in almost real time.